# implementasi stack from Visual Basic to Java netbeans

Tags: java, vb.net, stack

```
Public Class pros_stack
Dim stk As New Stack(Of barang)

Private Sub beli(ByVal brg As barang)
    stk.Push(brg)
    stock += brg.jml
End Sub

Private Function jual() As barang
    Dim hps As barang = stk.Pop
    stock -= hps.jml
    Return hps
End Function

Public Sub proses()
    Dim putar As Boolean = True
    Dim pilih As Integer
    Dim new_brg As barang
    '
    Console.Clear()
    history.Clear()
    '
    Try
        Console.WriteLine("               Proses STACK")
        Console.WriteLine("               ------------")
        While putar
            Console.WriteLine("               Menu")
            Console.WriteLine("               1. Beli")
            Console.WriteLine("               2. Jual")
            Console.WriteLine("               3. Selesai")
            Console.WriteLine()
            Console.Write("Pilih : ")
            pilih = Console.ReadLine
            If pilih = 1 Then ' BELI
                Console.WriteLine("               Proses Beli")
                Console.WriteLine("               ----------")
                Console.Write("Jumlah Barang : ")
                new_brg.jml = Console.ReadLine
                Console.Write("Harga Satuan : ")
                new_brg.hrg = Console.ReadLine
```

how can implement stack code like above in visual basic, can someone give me references. how to push array object with many variable. like new_brg.jml and new_brg.hrg into one stack object in java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equivalent in Java to the .NET Stack is java.util.Stack. I've also included the equivalent to the Console.WriteLine and Console.ReadLine methods below.

```
import java.util.*;

//stack:
Stack<barang> stk = new Stack<barang>();
stk.push(b);
b = stk.pop();

//console:
System.out.println(d);
x = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
```